# S3 Static Webpage Access Denied Error for ACL policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a webpage hosted in S3 which is to be accessed only by specific users within the account. For testing purpose, I added below bucket policy which has my iam arn specified in the Principal but I'm getting access denied error when trying to access the page (which is in that bucket) via S3 url https://s3.amazonaws.com/..... despite being signed in.

Can you please let me know what i'm doing wrong here.

Bucket Policy:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Id": "Policy1484430450679",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "Stmt1484430445422",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::123:user/testuser"
        },
        "Action": "s3:GetObject",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::testbucket/*"
    }
]}
```

If I give Principal as '*', then the webpage is accessible via S3 url.

Comment: Are your specific users using their AWS credentials to generate signed URLs to access the pages? If not, how does S3 recognize them as being those users?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I assumed that if you sign into the aws console the same cookie details will be used by amazon s3 endpoint for recognition of signed in user but that doesn't seem to be the case. I have tried the pre-signed url approach but the problem with that is the css and js used by the html have also to be presigned for access otherwise will get 403 error. So I have to expose these files globally and restrict the access for the html page alone which is not a good solution. I think I have to try IP level restriction to allow access within corporate network. Any ideas pls share.

Comment: *I assumed that if you sign into the aws console the same cookie details will be used by amazon s3 endpoint for recognition of signed in user...* As you see now, that is definitely not the case.  S3 isn't an application, it's a resource... so it has no sense of the viewer's identity.  If you select an object in the console and choose Actions > Download and then right-click and copy the link for inspection... you'll find that it's a pre-signed URL that the AWS console (the console itself *is* an application) creates on your behalf.